# Get the all unique permutation and combinations of 'where clause conditions' for my table in SQL Server

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, testing, permutation

I would like to see all possible unique scenarios of my data in a table.

```
    Mode    StartDate               EndDate
------------------------------------------------
0       1/1/2018                1/12/2018
0       1/5/2015                1/12/2018
0       3/8/2015                1/12/2019
0       1/1/2020                1/1/2020
0       5/5/2015                5/5/2015
1       1/1/2018                5/5/2015
1       5/8/1947                9/9/1902
1       4/4/2014                3/3/2013
1       1/4/2020                1/1/2001
1       3/8/2015                1/12/2019
1       19/11/1992              19/11/1992
```

## I can give the Input like

Operators=[<,>,=,......]
Operands=[mode, StartDate,EndDate,.....]

## I am expecting the result like

`0 and 1/1/2018`<`1/12/2018
 0 and 1/1/2020`=`1/1/2020
 1 and 1/1/2018`>`5/5/2015
 1 and 3/8/2015`<`1/12/2019
 1 and 19/11/1992`=`19/11/1992`

these are my unique patterns in my data.  So is there any query or java program to get these unique patterns of my data so that I can test my application with all possible scenarios.

Note: I am having a total of 6 six columns in my table. for sample purposes, I only gave 3 columns.

Comment: Please explain the logic for choosing calculating those results.

Comment: considering the only top(1) valid condition, let say
`0       1/1/2018                1/12/2018   ,
0       1/5/2015                1/12/2018   ,
0       3/8/2015                1/12/2019   `
all above statements are valid with '0 StartDate<EndDate' . So i am considering the top one for my application testing.  like that I want to pick all possible unique scenarios, to cover all test cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by generalizing the data into categories using window function and pick one from each set.
try the following:

```
;with cte as 
(
    select Mode, StartDate, EndDate, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Mode, case when CONVERT(date, StartDate, 103) < CONVERT(date, EndDate, 103) then 0 when CONVERT(date, StartDate, 103) = CONVERT(date, EndDate, 103) then 1 else 2 end order by Mode) rn
    from @tab
)

select Mode, StartDate, EndDate from cte 
where rn = 1
order by Mode,  CONVERT(date, StartDate, 103)
```

Please see db<>fiddle **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=60e019d630733a58ccf66219f95e4e75)**.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, you are a great hero!!, but how to get all combinations of where clause without static conditions. I will supply the operators[<,>,=] and operands as column names, then I should get all possible unique values like how you did now.

Comment: @RaviSharmananda Thanks! can you join the conditions to the final output as given [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=aa5fa3b27ac3ccb210042bd4a4d523d8)?

Comment: Hi Goodmorning!! sorry for the delay. Yes, your solution almost fulfilling my requirement but I need the dynamic automatic expressions in the partition clause.  PARTITION BY expression1, expression2, ...currently we are statically defining conditions in partition clause like `Mode, case when CONVERT(date, StartDate, 103) < CONVERT(date, EndDate, 103) then 0 when CONVERT(date, StartDate, 103) = CONVERT(date, EndDate, 103) then 1 else 2 end`